# In Laravel project images comming in json_decode format like ff1dgadfll but i want to show it in original format in admin stoarge how?

Tags: laravel

In laravel images comming in `json_decode` format like `jfhfkak56rs` but i want to show it in the admin panel in original path when my image name in `test.jpg` then it should be stored in admin `test.jpg` not in `json_decode` when i change the `json_decode` to `json_encode` that site showing an error message please help me.

here is my code.

```
@foreach (json_decode($cs->images, true) as $image)
    <li class="wd-casestudy">
        <img onClick="changeImage(this)" src="{{ productImage($image) }}" style="width:100%;cursor: pointer" alt="Partner">
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Are you saying that file uploads are being stored with gibberish filenames?